# Has one satellite's outgassing ever affected another satellite in the same fairing? Documented examples?

Tags: materials, fairings, manufacturing, smallsat, outgassing

At about `01:31` in Scott Manley's new video [RocketLab & Reusable Rockets - Plasma Knifes, Ballutes, Helicopters and... Elephants](https://youtu.be/lQNLoPoqJ9g?t=91) he says:

> This occurs during a small sat conference, and I don’t doubt the people there were rather concerned since SpaceX took the opportunity to announce that they were going to offer flights to space for payloads of 150 kilograms or less, for the sum of like two and a half million dollars, which is half of what rocket lab is offering.
>
> Of course the drawback is that your satellite has to share a launch with a bunch of other spacecraft all clustered inside the fairing, and you know some of them might smell, or as they say in the business, they might outgas, and you might think that I’m joking here, **but if a satellite is outgassing it can really mess up your sensors.**

Outgassing is discussed in the following questions and/or their answers.

- [How serious a problem can outgassing of satellites be?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18308/12102)
- [What are the common space application adhesives used in Earth orbiting satellites?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9046/12102)
- [Why is the Aeolus space laser losing power so quickly?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36151/12102)
- [Do things get dirty in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17196/12102)

But I'd like to ask:

**Question:** Has one satellite's outgassing ever affected **another satellite** in the same fairing? Are there any documented examples of this happening? Examples don't necessarily have to be a cubesats or smallsats.

---

Comment: Very cool question! I wish I had some answers. My initial thoughts are 1) the getting is elected quite early. Perhaps there is more risk on the ground during assembly, transport, and fueling... and 2) I would hope sensitive satellites like telescopes would insist on no secondary payloads partially for this reason, although I don’t have evidence:D

Comment: @AndrewW. the [Dove satellites](https://www.satimagingcorp.com/satellite-sensors/other-satellite-sensors/dove-3m/) are examples of telescopes that while pushed to their optical limit in resolution can't opt for dedicated launches at the moment.

Comment: It's hard to prove a negative, but to my knowledge no secondary payload has ever had a detrimental effect on the primary. (Out gassing, collision, damage, or any other effect)